# Curtain rod came off

Tags: curtain-rail

[image]

What type of wall is it? I am new to this . How do i fix it and hang rod again. My curtains are heavy

Answer (score 2):

This will require you to repair the area (similar to the repaired areas a few inches to the right of your current problem, which looks to be a previous issue identical to your current issue).

After repair, you will need to select and use appropriate *hollow wall anchors*, of which there are many types available depending on the weight and service of the material being attached. My presumption would be that either your curtains are heavy, or there is some other reason that the bracket was torn from the wall.

Use your Google-Fu to research different styles/types of anchors for different applications; there are just too many options to go into depth about here...

BTW, I have had good luck with these:

[image]

You will have the best luck if you are able to choose a new bracket location where you have some confidence that the wall is sound, rather than trying to anchor in a location where there was previous damage...

Comment: To be honest the damage is due to a bad installer using straight wood screws into drywall.  The inside of the wall shouldn't be damaged since it wasn't an anchor that got ripped out.  This specific damage can still handle an anchor fine, assuming it is all installed properly and the hole is drilled properly.

Answer (score 2):

It's very difficult to get hardware to hold for long in drywall. I had this problem with my toilet paper holder. For a long time it was just kind of hanging off the wall a little, but because I didn't fix it, eventually it came off. I used a nice piece of stained wood to backplate the holder, fixing the wood to studs and then the tp holder to the wood. That looked OK for a bathroom toilet holder, but it might not be attractive on a window unless the curtains could hide the wood. Get a stud finder from a hardware store (they are cheap) and try to find a stud (sturdy wood behind the drywall) near where you need to anchor the window hardware. Screw into the stud instead of just drywall. Studs are usually 16" apart. Use drywall patch to fix the tear in the wall and then touch up the paint. Maybe you need to use more support brackets in the middle of the rod to take pressure off the main brackets.

Comment: Proper heavy duty drywall anchors like a toggle bolt can hold a lot.  Placing one down every 3 inches will easily hold some of the heavier furniture.